Different solutions between Mathematica and Wolfram Alpha
I started to use Mathematica just recently and tried to do the following simple integral:
The result I get from
Integrate[1/(Exp[x]+1),x]

is
-2 ArcTanh[1+2*Exp[x]]] 

That is kinda not what I expected. Simplifying give me the same result.
All other CAS (including Wolfram Alpha!) gave me the following
-ln(exp(x)+1)+x

How do I force Mathematica to give me a nice answer like this. -2 ArcTanh[1+2*Exp[x]]] doesn't even seems right to me idk?
Any hint / advice would be appreciated.

An indefinite integral is an antiderivative. Antiderivatives that differ by a constant are all valid. The derivative of both of the results return the original integrand.

There is even a simpler form: $-\log \left(e^{-x}+1\right) $, -Log[E^-x + 1].

@azerbajdzan: LeafCount[Log[1/(E^-x + 1)]] results in 10 as well as LeafCount[x - Log[1 + E^x]], so your words do not correspond to reality.

I vote to keep this question open, because it serves as a great example that indefinite integrals are not one particular function but a whole class of functions that can all differ in an additive term. About the only stipulation that M makes is that the derivatives are all the same (the integrand). It's a common mistake made by beginners. Remember that the anti-derivative is defined through the derivative (the integrand).

Mathematica v12.2 evaluates Integrate[1/(Exp[x] + 1), x]==x - Log[1 + E^x]

Transform result -2 ArcTanh[1 + 2*Exp[x]] // TrigToExp : Log[-2 E^x] - Log[2 + 2 E^x]

@UlrichNeumann: Is Log[-2 E^x] not a complex number?

@user64494 Probably yes, but can be transformed to Log[-2]+x  , constant Log[-2] does not interest.

I see no difference. Here is result from different integrators
data={{"derivativedivides",Log[Exp[x]]-Log[Exp[x]+1]},
{"Norman algorithm",x-Log[Exp[x]+1]},
{"Rich algorithm",x-Log[Exp[x]+1]},
{"Parallel Rich algorithm",x-Log[Exp[x]+1]},
{"Fricas ",x-Log[Exp[x]+1]},
{"Maxima ",x-Log[Exp[x]+1]},
{"Giac ",x-Log[Exp[x]+1]},
{"Rubi ",x-Log[1+E^x]},
{"Mathematica",-2 ArcTanh[1+2 E^x]},
{"MUPAD",x-Log[Exp[x]+1]},
{"Reduce",x-Log[Exp[x]+1]}};

lc = LeafCount[#] & /@ data[[All, 2]];
def = D[#, x] & /@ data[[All, 2]];
data = Join[data, Partition[lc, 1], 2];
data = Join[data, Partition[def, 1], 2];
data = Join[{{"algorithm", "anti-derivative", "leaf count", 
     "derivative of anti-derivative"}}, data];
Grid[data, Frame -> All]


Only first algorithm has larger leaf count.
Plot of antiderivatives all identical
Plot[Evaluate@data[[All,2]],{x,-5,5},PlotLegends->data[[All,1]]]



Let us find an antiderivative as a definite integral.
Integrate[1/(Exp[t] + 1), {t, 0, x},  Assumptions -> x \[Element] Reals]


x + Log[2] - Log[1 + E^x]


Just to compare. The command of Maple 2024 int(1/(exp(x) + 1), x) performs ln(exp(x)) - ln(exp(x) + 1). Then simplify(%,symbolic) outputs x-ln(exp(x)+1).
